# How can I write a math quiz, with random numbers, in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The best math quiz I have currently is:

```
answer = ''
while not (answer == '75'):
answer = raw_input('What is 5 x 15?   ')
if answer == '75':
    print ' '
    print 'You are correct' 

    answer1 = ''
    while not (answer1 == '72'):
        answer1 = raw_input('What is 8 x 9?   ')
        if answer1 == '72':
            print ' '
            print 'You are correct'

            answer2 = ' '
            while not (answer2 == '0'):
                answer2 = raw_input('What is 5 x 0?   ')
                if answer2 == '0':
                    print' '
                    print'You are correct'

                    answer3 = ''
                    while not (answer3 == '18'):
                        answer3 = raw_input('what is 6 x 3?   ')
                        if answer3 == '18':
                            print ''
                            print 'You are correct'
                        else:
                            print 'You are incorrect'
                else:
                    print'You are incorrect'
        else:
            print 'You are incorrect'
            continue
else:
    print 'You are incorrect'
    continue
```

To me, at least, it feels that this code is way too long for only 4 questions to answer. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to make a math quiz with random numbers, so you don't have to create each question.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. You can definitely simplify it, and absolutely generate random questions.

Comment: You are obviously learning so probably giving you solution here would hurt more than help. So just to point in a direction: why not have list of questions and answers instead?

Comment: The hint @tomasz-plaskota gave you is the key to the answer to cleaning this up a ton.

Comment: I am also specifically asking how to do it, I have seen the code to do it, but it was code for other languages besides python 2 - forgot to mention this in my question...

Comment: First, understand what the other code is doing. Then, translate that logic into Python. If you have *specific* questions about a particular point of translation, that is on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the questions dynamically like this:

```
from random import randint
q = ''
while not q.capitalize() == 'N':
    num1 = randint(0, 100)
    num2 = randint(0, 100)
    answer = input("What is " + str(num1) + " x " + str(num2) + " ? ")
    if answer == (num1 * num2):
        print "Correct"
    else:
        print "Incorrect"

    q = raw_input("Do you want to continue: Y/N? ")
```

In your quiz only three things are changed, they are `num1` and `num2` which as a result changes `answer`. That means you can reuse everything else and randomly generate the `num1` and `num2`.